# Keydown event, undesired native behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, keydown

I have a situation very similar to this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8kbx4/

Basically, it is a table with scrolling which doesn't show all the columns at the same time. The browsers (at least, FF and Chrome) have a weird native behaviour when those next steps are achieved:

- Focus on the input field, which is in one of the last columns.
- Left scroll to the beginning of the table (in the example, the column "a").
- Press a key.

In that moment, after the `keyDown()`'s execution event, the table scrolls until the column which contains the "focused" input. How can i avoid this behaviour without stopping the propagation of the following events (like the change of the input value, etc.)?

Comment: Did you intend to include the JS you tried in your Fiddle? I didn't see it. I'm able to reproduce the behavior you described.

Comment: I don't see the problem you're describing (I'm familiar with the issue) but FF 29 doesn't produce it on jsFiddle.

Comment: Don't you? I'm using FF v29.0.1 (Mac) and I can reproduce the behaviour which I'm explaining :S

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `event.preventDefault()` to stop native behaviour?

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

For example,

```
$(selector).mouseDown(function(event) { // pass in the event
  event.preventDefault();               // stop the default browser behavior.
  // then goes your code.
});
```

Comment: I tried that, of course. Basically the problem is that I don't want to avoid the rest of the default behaviours (For instance, the propagation of the keydown event assigns a value for the input field and does tabbing). The reimplementation of all these stuff can be a mess and it should be avoided.

Comment: "... without stopping the propagation"

Comment: Wow. That's... possible?

Comment: Ok, the other way to implement that is to emulate the same default behaviour (change value and tabs, shift + tabs, etc.) which browser does. Do you thing you can emulate that in a simple way?